# Onramp Kit restrictions (chains / jurisdiction)

Tags: safe-core-sdk

Noticed the folllowing text

> Consider that the Onramp kit will only work on Mumbai test chain and US based connection.

on the `account-abstraction-demo-ui` demo project. Do these restrictions apply to production use as well, or is this restriction in place just for the demo you offer?

In any case, it would be nice to have a section on the docs regarding any restrictions (either underlying chain or jurisdiction) in place for the Onramp Kit - or separately for the offered providers.